# Can this roof flashing membrane be glued back down?

Tags: deck, roofing, flashing

New house, roof deck. Membrane (I think it's flashing) pulling away from the wall underneath the siding. I'm not certain what type of membrane it is, but it feels rubbery. Can I just glue it back down, or is a more extensive repair required?

[image: membrane separation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably is rubber and you can try to glue it back up, but I doubt it will stick. The important thing when gluing rubber is that it is clean. The rubber can be cleaned with gasoline, but consider the location, such a thing would be a terrible idea.

That is flashing against a wall. Rubber never stays stuck in that situation because it shrinks with age (no matter what the rubber salesman said). Termination bar should have been used on day one, but since it wasn't, you are going to have to install it now.

Roofing termination bar (we always called it turnbar) is a flat piece of aluminum with screw holes and an outward bend on top. The termination bar gets bolted to the wall with the rubber behind. The upper lip holds the caulking to keep water from going behind the rubber.

If you want to use real termination bar then you will probably have to go to a roofing store.

The caulking that you use, which, due to location, will have to be applied before the turn bar installation, can NOT contain petroleum, grease, or tar. If it does, then the caulking will eat the rubber. Rubberized lap-sealant is used against rubber. It is also available from your nearest flat roofing supply house.

You have found yourself in a specialty trade situation. You may have to get imaginative to use products from Home Depot, but now that you understand the goal, I think you will be fine no matter what you choose to do.

Comment: Surface prep is to be done with alcohol. Anything else you're likely to have on hand will leave residue, i.e., mineral spirits. Or be carcinogenic and/or likely to explode. "Surfaces can be degreased using volatile solvents such as toluene, acetone, methyl ethyl ketone, methyl alcohol, isopropyl alcohol and trichloroethylene." *Surface Preparation For Rubbers* https://www.masterbond.com/resources/surface-preparation-for-rubbers

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, that rubber-like membrane is supposed to be tucked up behind the bottom row of siding.  Looks like it was added without pulling the siding out to tuck the membrane under.

Some flashing may work.  Cut a piece 1" - 2" wide and as long as you can manage.  Then gently with a small pry bar pull the bottom of the siding out a bit.  You don't need much, 1/16" should do it.  Slide the flashing up and under the siding so that 1/2" or 1" hangs out and overlaps the rubber membrane.  Typical flashing installation - under the piece above, and over the piece below.

Comment: Flash the flashing, +1. 'termination bars' (from the other answer) hold flashing in, they don't flash anything.